# Crontab not finding python modules

Tags: python, ubuntu, cron

Hello i have been following stackoverflow posts and im unable to get the crontab to run my python scripts in ubuntu.

After talking with the user below, i have modified my file but am not getting a "moduleNotFoundError: No module named aioredis"

when i deactivate my py3.9 venv environment, and call python feed_ingestor_to_postgres.py i get the same error.  so clearly the pipenv isn't activating for me.  any suggestions?

my launcher.sh file:

```
#!/bin/bash
  
WORKDIR=$( cd "$( dirname "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}" )" && pwd )
cd $WORKDIR

activate(){
        ../../env/bin/activate
}


python3 feed_ingestor_to_postgres.py
```

my crontab file:

```
* * * * * echo "Great cron, awesome job!" > /var/log/nonsense
* * * * * /home/ubuntu/phobos/phobos-trading-engine/exchange_feeds/launcher.sh
```

I have no idea what else to do here.  any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To manage python scripts from the crontab more easily, I would advise to use a simple shell wrapper script, for example "launcher.sh" which will be called by the crontab. The launcher will cd to the script location, manage the virtualenv, or possibly set env vars if required:

```
#!/bin/bash

WORKDIR=$( cd "$( dirname "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}" )" && pwd )
cd $WORKDIR

source ../../env/bin/activate
python feed_ingestor_to_postgres.py
```

Then in the crontab, call the launcher instead of your python script:

```
* * * * *       ~/path/to/launcher.sh
```

It will be much more flexible than editing the crontab directly

Comment: thanks it almost worked, 
now i am getting a permission denied when i tried your method: 
/home/ubuntu/research/trading-engine/feeds/launcher.sh: Permission denied

Comment: Actually, after making the change ../../env/bin/activate and chmod 777 activate, 
now i get a new error:

No module named 'aioredis'

Why is it not recognizing my pip packages?

Comment: Ah right, forgot to mention that you needed a "chmod +x" to make the launcher.sh executable. For the modules like aioredis, are they properly installed in the virtualenv? You can check by sourcing the activate script then running "pip list", then "pip install aioredis". Note that for python modules in general, I would advise to manage them directly with pip, rather than using distribution provided packages (https://packages.ubuntu.com/impish/python3-aioredis) which will perform a global install, possibly explaining why you can't import it from the virtualenv

Comment: i am using pip, they are properly installed.  i think when i do 
../../env/bin/activate, its not activating the virtual environment.  what can i do to activate this? 
i tried source ../../bin/activate but that doesn't work

Comment: I made the following changes and its still not activating, its a problem with activating the virtual environment, 
#!/bin/bash
  
WORKDIR=$( cd "$( dirname "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}" )" && pwd )
cd $WORKDIR

activate(){
        ../../env/bin/activate
}
python3 feed_ingestor_to_postgres.py

Comment: here you are defining the activate function but not calling it. Unless you have a good reason to define a function in the launcher, I would remove the definition and curly braces around the "../../env/bin/activate". Also note that you need to add a "." or "source" before the path to evaluate the activate file. I updated my sample code accordingly